# SQL Server Function/Proc evaluate an expression(s) return an error if not valid

Tags: sql-server

I would like to take the code below and create a common function to pass in one or more expressions and to return back an error of my choosing.

Example Code:

```
IF @Variable1 IS NULL AND @Variable IS NULL or @Variable3 is not null
    BEGIN

        -- EITHER DATASET NAME OR ID MUST BE SUPPLIED.
        SET @_msg = 'There was an error'
        SET @_returnValue = -1
        GOTO ERROR_HANDLER
    END
ERROR_HANDLER: 

    -- CREATE THE CLOSING MESSAGE.
    IF @_returnValue <> 0
        RAISERROR(@_msg, 18, 2) WITH SETERROR

    RETURN @_returnValue
```

From the above, it would be nice to say something like this below where I could reuse the proc/function and make the code less clutered.

```
exec ValidateMultipleConditions @Variable1 + 'IS NULL AND ' + @Variable +   'IS NULL or ' + @Variable3 + ' is not null'
```

Anyway, I think with dynamic SQL being passed in this way I could do something where an complete expression could be sent evaluated, validated and then the code continues or stops with an error.

I wanted to see if the community had better ways of doing this or if I'm on the right path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I get your question right. But you can easily create an procedure (if it's needed).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.errorout @message nvarchar(100), @sev int, @state int 
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(@message,@sev,@state) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

But I won't use this at all. I would call RAISERROR() in the place where it occurs, as it will give you more accurate line numbers and procedures in the errorlog.